# Filament AttachAction and ->recordSelectOptionsQuery

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I got an Order where I can attach a Privateclass. And I only want to see Privateclasses to current Event (to which this order belongs). So this is working:

```
AttachAction::make()
->recordSelectOptionsQuery(fn (Builder $query, Component $livewire) => $query->where('event_id', $livewire->ownerRecord->event_id))
->preloadRecordSelect()
```

Now I get the dates back and can choose between them. But I also need the instructor's name through a pivot table in the same drop down. And I want to format the dates returned. Is that possible?

A.I. suggested this (but displayUsing is not part of AttachAction):

```
AttachAction::make()
    ->recordSelectOptionsQuery(function (Builder $query, Component $livewire) {
        return $query
            ->where('event_id', $livewire->ownerRecord->event_id)
            ->join('privateclass_instructor', 'privateclasses.id', '=', 'privateclass_instructor.privateclass_id')
            ->join('instructors', 'privateclass_instructor.instructor_id', '=', 'instructors.id')
            ->selectRaw("privateclasses.id, CONCAT(privateclasses.date, ' - ', instructors.name) as display_name");
    })
    ->displayUsing(function ($instance) {
        return $instance->display_name;
    })
    ->preloadRecordSelect();
```